# How to render googlevis in flexdashboard

Tags: r, googlevis, flexdashboard

I'm trying to use GoogleVis with the new package [FlexDashboard](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/), which is like the intersection between a basic .Rd and shinyDashboards. It's basically a non-shiny dashboard.

Anyway, I'm trying to embed a googleVis object, which [doesn't seem to be supported by default](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/26), but I can get the html to show up in the output, so there must be a way! Can we come up with some hack? Maybe combining either `plot()` or `renderGvis()` combined with [some kind of hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490026/knitr-does-not-render-googlevis)? Ormessing with setting `op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')`?

I have failed, but maybe someone else can figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the awesome answer from Michal Majka at [Conditional reactive logic shiny based flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801666/conditional-reactive-logic-shiny-based-flexdashboard) you can do something like this

````
---
title: "Test gvisTable"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows

runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(googleVis)

```

Column {data-height=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart c

```{r}
#create a ui interaction:
uiOutput("dynamic")

#render the ui:
output$dynamic <- renderUI({ 
   htmlOutput("myTable")
})

#here is your server activity:
output$myTable <- renderGvis({    
    gvisTable(Population )       
  })
```
````

Comment: I give u a +1 for the effort, but if I wanted shiny then I'd just go w/ shinydashboard. Nice hack tho..

Comment: Fair enough, I guess, but I would point out that you specifically asked for "some kind of hack" (that is, if defining a runtime is even a hack), and secondly shinydashboard is not a mark down format so combining two useful packages into one solution is not the same as just using one.